# Need to remove 'drupal' from html attributes

Tags: 8

I've been tasked with removing 'drupal' from front end source code and I've managed to remove most by modifying templates and using theme hooks, but I'm struggling to remove it from a `<script>` tag on the bottom of the page:

```
<script type="application/json" data-drupal-selector="drupal-settings-json">
```

I know that this comes from core/lib/Drupal/Core/Asset/JsCollectionRenderer, but I don't know how to modify it without creating a patch or overriding the class (which I want to avoid).

Is there a preprocess hook I can use to remove it? I have not found one that contains that text.

Comment: Do you want to remove it entirely? Because I believe that's an important tag for functionality.

Comment: @Matt  I just want to remove the attribute: data-drupal-selector="drupal-settings-json"

Comment: I believe that attribute is necessary and used as a selector

Comment: For example it's used by the drupalSeettingsLoader.es6.js here:   const settingsElement = document.querySelector(
    'head > script[type="application/json"][data-drupal-selector="drupal-settings-json"], body > script[type="application/json"][data-drupal-selector="drupal-settings-json"]',
  );

Comment: @Matt   Hmm. I suspected that may be the case. Is there any way I can hide it?  The requirement is that they don't want anyone to know the site is using Drupal by viewing the HTML source code.

Comment: it would be really dirty and wouldn't work if they turned off javascript but I believe you could technically remove it after document ready with custom javascript. I'm not positive but I believe after document ready, the things using that selector might already be loaded.

Comment: @Matt  OK. I will consider that approach. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Good luck. Again I'm not 100% positive.

Comment: You can't prevent someone from detecting that you're using Drupal. If you remove all occurrences of "drupal" from the HTML source, there are still many other clues that give it away. And even if you remove all clues from the HTML source (I don't think that's really possible) then there are still many other ways to detect that your site is using Drupal. So if this "requirement" is for security purposes then it's misguided - it would be much better to ASSUME an attacker KNOWS you're using Drupal than to try to protect yourself by hiding that fact.

Comment: Any Solution? I Just want to check.